# Two spheres of equal radius are taken out by cutting from a solid cube

Tags: geometry

Two spheres of equal radius are taken out by cutting from a solid cube with a side of (12 + 4√3) cm. What is the maximum volume (in cm3) of each sphere?
My approach: suppose side of cube =1 and let the sphere be of unequal size with diameter D and d,
$$\sqrt3=D+d+x+y....(1
)$$ [image]
where x and y are corner distances.

$$x=r\sqrt2-r$$
$$\implies x=D/\sqrt2-D/2 $$
similarly $$y=d/\sqrt2-d/2$$
Putting in 1 and putting $$d=D$$
$$\sqrt3=2D+D\sqrt2-D=D(1+\sqrt2)$$
$$Radius =\sqrt3/2(1+\sqrt2)$$
scaling it by 12+4$\sqrt3$,
$$radius =(12\sqrt3+12)/2(1+\sqrt2)$$
Where am i getting it wrong ?

Comment: That line segment $x$ does not lie in the flat plane of the picture you drew. It is a segment of the main diagonal of the cube. If you include the missing third dimension, it has length $r\sqrt{3}-r$.

Comment: It is however easiest to divide that main diagonal in three parts: from cube corner, to sphere centre 1, to sphere centre 2, to opposite cube corner. So don't start with adding diameters, but with radii.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the parts are not equal, how does it help me ? are you suggesting that x=corner distance =$\sqrt3$r-r?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis how do you get $\sqrt3$ instead of $\sqrt2$

Comment: Calculate the distance from the corner of the cube to the centre of the sphere near that corner. This is a distance of $r$ along all three axes, so $r\sqrt{3}$. The distance $x$, which is from a corner of a cube to the surface of the sphere is $r$ less than that. (But you don't really need to calculate $x$ since it is easier to use the original distance of $r\sqrt{3}$ to the sphere's centre when solving the rest of the problem.)

Comment: The title and first sentence say the spheres are equal, but when you work on the problem you allow them to be unequal.  The equal case is much easier.  Which is it?

Comment: @Ross Millikan for sake of clear notation,  I did that, but after few steps ,I put d=D

Comment: which exam question is it from? thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The maximum volume is achieved when the two spheres are placed along diagonal line of the cube.

Let $r$ be the radius, $d$ the diagonal of the cube and $\theta$ the angle formed by the diagonal line and the face of the cube. It follows that

$$ \cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}, \>\>\> \sin\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$$

Then, the diagonal line calculated from the spheres is,

$$ d = 2r + 2\frac{r}{\sin\theta}$$

Given that $d= \sqrt 3 (12+4\sqrt 3)$, we get

$$2(1+\sqrt 3)r= \sqrt 3 (12+4\sqrt 3)$$

Solve for the radius

$$r= 6$$

Comment: how did you get value of cos(@) = root(2)/root(3)?

Comment: @AngelusMortis - Note that the diagonal of the cube is $c=\sqrt3$ and the diagonal of the face is $a=\sqrt2$. Thus, $\cos\theta = \frac ac = \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}$

Comment: but isn't the diagonal of face of cube is (12 + 4√3)*root(2)

Comment: @AngelusMortis - To be more precise. Let the side s =  (12 + 4√3). Then, a = √2s and c = √3s. So, $\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt2 s}{\sqrt3 s}=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}$

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

If it was 1 sphere, the radius would be $x$ inside the cube. And so the side of the cube would be $2x$. And so the diagonal of this cube would be $\sqrt{3} \cdot 2x$

And so the, going from one diagonal to the other would be [$(\sqrt{3}-1)x$] [$x$] [$x$] [$(\sqrt{3}-1)x$] ...the [$x$][$x$] part would be the 2 radii making the diameter of sphere.

If there were two spheres of same size, it would be this: [$(\sqrt{3}-1)x] [$x$] [$x$] [$x$] [$x$] [$(\sqrt{3}-1)x]. But now the length of the diagonal is $(2 \sqrt{3}+2)x$

Since the original side length was supposed to be $12+4 \sqrt{3}$, our diagonal is $(12+4 \sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3})=12 \sqrt{3}+12$.

And since the diagonal is also $(2 \sqrt{3}+2)x$, then the $x=6$. So the radius is $6$ and therefore volume is $288 \pi cm^3$

Comment: i can not understand your notation.plz edit your answer